# Is this possible to add custom query in Kibana dashboard which is hidden from logged in user?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, lucene, kibana

Is this possible to add custom query in Kibana dashboard  which is hidden from logged in user. For example, I have index which have data of multiple users i want user can see only own data. For that i have user_id in each document which are  stored in Elasticsearch.

Actually, I want when user log in, add a hidden field which is user_id and when he  creating query for dashboard a custom query automatically add in query  which is generated by Kibana.Is this possible ? Or something similar?